# Filter buttons are not working with Isotope and Wordpress custom post type

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, filtering, jquery-isotope

I've been trying to fix this issue for a few hours now and I'm at the end of my tether with it. Not sure what the issue is here.

I've setup Isotope on my bespoke Wordpress theme for my company website. I would love to be able to filter the portfolio.

Here is the link to the page: [http://www.wildemedia.co.uk/portfolio/](http://www.wildemedia.co.uk/portfolio)

This is the jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var $container = $('#isotope-list');
  $container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode: 'masonry'
  });

  //Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from the others
  var $optionSets = $('#filters'),
    $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

  $optionLinks.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
      return false;
    } < br >
      var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
    $optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    //When an item is clicked, sort the items.
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
      filter: selector
    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

This is the PHP code from my Portfolio custom post type file:

```
<div class="wrap">


    <ul id="filters">
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">Everything</a></li>
     <?php 
     $terms = get_terms("portfolio-categories"); // get all categories, but you can use any taxonomy
     $count = count($terms); //How many are they?
     if ( $count > 0 ){  //If there are more than 0 terms
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //for each term:
     echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>\n";
     //create a list item with the current term slug for sorting, and name for label
     }
     } 
     ?>
    </ul>

    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=portfolio&posts_per_page=50' ); //Check the WP_Query docs to see how you can limit which posts to display ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div id="isotope-list">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
     $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "portfolio-categories" );  //Get the terms for this particular item
     $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
     foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
     $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
     }
     ?> 
     <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item"> <?php // 'item' is used as an identifier (see Setp 5, line 6) ?>
     <div class="img">
        <a title="<?=$title?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></a>
     </div>

     <div class="item_content">

     <?php echo wpdocs_custom_taxonomies_terms_links(); ?>


     <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

     <div class="grey_separator"></div>

     <p><?php print get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 

     <a class="portfolio_view_more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View More</a>

     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
     </div> <!-- end item -->
        <?php endwhile;  ?>
        </div> <!-- end isotope-list -->
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Hi, you don't seem to ask a direct question? You might want to edit to clarify what exactly isn't doing what your trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The dev console on your website says that `$(...).isotope()` is not a function. I also see that your `isotope.pkgd.js` is kept in header before the `scripts.js` but that does not always ensure that the flow and that the library would be available at the time of executing the JS code in scripts.js

You can try two things,

Initialise isotope after `jQuery(window).load` so that the library is already loaded

OR

at the time of enqueuing `scripts.js` put isotope.pkgd.js's handle in dependency list i.e.

For example you included your isotope library like this

```
wp_enqueue_scripts( 'isotope', 'link-to-isotope-library', ... );
```

Then include the `scripts.js` as

```
wp_enqueue_scripts( 'scripts', 'scripts.js-link', array('isotope'), FALSE, true );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I've since fixed it, even though it was minutes ago that I posted it. I was linking to an older version of jQuery, removed that link and now it seems to be working. Damn this stuff gives me a headache!

Comment: Post your answer and mark it the solution, to close this thread